# Is there a word or phrase for walking into a room to get something but then forgetting what you went in there to get?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm fairly certain this has happened to all of us at some point: You go into a room to get something, but once you're there, you can't remember what you intended to get. It seems like a specific, common phenomenon like this must have a name, but I can't think of it. Does anyone know a name (either formal or slang) for this?

I don't want a general term like **forgetfulness** or **absent-mindedness**, which could apply to all sorts of forgetting, or a term for not being able to remember a certain word. I'm looking for a word or phrase that describes this one specific situation of forgetting what you need to get as soon as you go to get it.

Comment: Alzheimer's, definitely!

Comment: "forgetting"....

Comment: What you want is sort of the opposite of _treppenwitz_ or _l'esprit de l'escalier_.  I can't think of an English word/name for what you want. Perhaps you could craft something using those as a jumping off point?

Comment: hmmm - as often as it happens, you'd think this group would know it and I hope someone does.  My cohorts call it "Sometimers Disease" or CRS-syndrome (for Can't Remember S**T). :-)

Comment: Why would you expect there to be a word? Do you know such a word in any other language? Is there a word for seeing your neighbour in town, but not getting the chance to speak? Or is there a word for a person who has a different swear word for every month of the year, or for someone who eats fish and chips on Thursdays and a pie on a Friday and plays golf on Saturday?  These sorts of questions which seem to demand that a word be sought to describe any and every circumstance in life become quite tiresome. Why not use some descriptive creativity?

Comment: My doctor calls it O.L.D. syndrome...

Comment: There is a well-established idiom for thinking of something clever that you could have said earlier but failed to summon to mind in timely fashion: _staircase wit_. Along the same lines, getting halfway down a staircase and realizing that you don't know why you're there could reasonably be called _staircase witlessness_.

Comment: @WS2 It turns out there is a name for it, so I believe my question is justified. Everyone is familiar with the concept--scientific studies have been conducted to find out its cause, so why wouldn't it have a name? A scientific journal isn't going to publish a study on "that one thing that happens sometimes." Concepts are much easier to talk about when they have a name. That's why English takes words like _schadenfreude_ from other languages--we'll always prefer a word to a description.

Comment: @Nicole - I like your question, and upvoted it. I am thrilled that ermanen gave an answer. Please ask as many questions as your heart desires and your inquisitive mind comes up with.

Comment: @WS2 - That's not the only thing that becomes tiresome! While I gave the same answer (as a supportable answer) this very day, it's actually fun when one finds that there actually is a word (or words) for something like this. The marvels of language!

Comment: It's called "fridgenesia."

Comment: Not as specific as you're looking for, but I've heard "brain fart" used in these situations.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In psychology, it is called ***doorway effect*** or ***location updating effect***.

> Researchers already know that walking from one space to another makes people more likely to forget tasks when compared to others who don’t make such a transition. Called **“location-updating effect”** the phenomenon also causes people transitioning between rooms (even virtual ones) to take more time while attempting to recall items from memory.
>
> [news.discovery.com](http://news.discovery.com/human/psychology/walking-rooms-forget-111123.htm)

It happens both in virtual and real environments; and it is explained that leaving a place and entering a new one is served as an *event boundary* in the mind and memory refreshes itself for the new information.

> This **“doorway effect”** appears to be quite general.  It doesn't seem to matter, for instance, whether the virtual environments are displayed on a 66” flat screen or a 17” CRT.  In one study, Radvansky and his colleagues tested the doorway effect in real rooms in their lab.  Participants traversed a real-world environment, carrying physical objects and setting them down on actual tables.  The objects were carried in shoeboxes to keep participants from peeking during the quizzes, but otherwise the procedure was more or less the same as in virtual reality.  Sure enough, the doorway effect revealed itself:  Memory was worse after passing through a doorway than after walking the same distance within a single room.
>
> [scientificamerican.com](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-walking-through-doorway-makes-you-forget/)

Comment: I agree, this effect is also called "event boundary effect". Not sure, if it answers the OP's question, being little more wide, than they request, but it`s still the very phenomena's description.

Comment: Now that you have given it a name you have institutionalised the condition. That will now affect the way in which we think about it. It is not always a good idea to have names for things, in my view. They can become inhibitors to understanding, by compressing a range of conditions into a single descriptor.

Comment: @WS2 "institutionalised the condition" Luckily, as an American, I'm not too worried about that eventuality. We don't even bother to institutionalize severe schizophrenics, so me and my forgetful ways should be... ah... um... rhymes with "dine"? Whatever.

Comment: Cool!!! New names for things!

Comment: @WS2 Where does ermanen claim to have been the inventor of the term?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I wasn't actually blaming ermanem, and if it seemed like that I apologise. As a society we put names on things far too readily. It is all part of the process of *dumbing down*, creating a language that the simplest person can understand.

Comment: I've learned something new, and think that the effect is important enough to be given a name. I also think that these names are more appropriate than is sometimes the case.

Comment: @WS2 "As a society we put names on things far too readily." I'm sure there's a name for thinking that way.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Take for example an extremely powerful word like *cancer*. It covers such a range of conditions that it would undoubtedly be better if it didn't exist. As it is, it has, over the last century, taken on a life of its own as a very blunt semantic instrument. This is what I meant by institutionalisation.

Comment: @WS2 Certainly. But 'doorway effect' or 'location updating effect' isn't going to have such power. The effect seems real enough ('Researchers already know that walking from one space to another makes people more likely to forget tasks when compared to others who don’t make such a transition.') and isn't claimed to be the sole factor involved. This answer seems well liked.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not applicable to all ages, but it's often called a ***senior moment***.

Comment: This is not specific to walking into a room.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Do we know that there is a condition which is specific to walking into a room?

Comment: @WS2 All right, 'This is in no way indicating the tie-in (which ermanen cites evidence of) between change of location and quality of short-term memory'. Though the term 'doorway effect' surely makes complaints that 'walking into a room' may not be used as a transparent metaphor captious.

Answer (score 2):

'Destinesia' is an apt word...creative and fitting in one stroke;
destination + amnesia

Comment: Sounds like a creatively joined word, although you should add a cautionary notice that the word either "doesn't exist yet"/is new, or is on the lower scale of common words. Found some entries for it on Urban dictionary mainly. I like it.

Comment: Good answers on ELU require supporting references, linked and attributed. UD is not a suitable single source for standard terms.

Answer (score 0):

According to [The Meaning Of Liff](https://www.panmacmillan.com/authors/douglas-adams/the-meaning-of-liff/9780752227597):

> **Woking** (ptcpl.vb.): Standing in the kitchen wondering what you came in here for.

Comment: Good answers on ELU require supporting references, linked and attributed. UD and The Meaning of Liff are not suitable single sources for standard terms

Answer (score 0):

In certain cases, it may be referred to as **brain fog** or **[clouding of consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clouding_of_consciousness)**.

In relation to this (but not within the specific scoping of the OP), the term used for the equivalent phenomenon – but in a serious medical context – is **[aMCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mild_cognitive_impairment)** (amnestic Mild Cognitive Impairment).

Comment: To clarify, the term itself does not implicitly include "walking into a room" as a criterion.  However, as someone who suffers from it due to a medical comorbidity, that exact situation is how it usually occurs a large majority of the time (at least as far as I can remember).

Answer (score -1):

*Disorientation* describes the state.

Comment: This is not specific to walking into a room.

Answer (score -2):

AH! Damn! It's at the [tip of my tongue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tip_of_the_tongue)...

(Or, at least, it's a related / similar-feeling effect.)

Comment: This is not specific to walking into a room.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Mainly, I gave this answer because, even if it's not specific to walking into a room, it's a similar effect, and I anticipated that the same search terms could ostensibly bring someone to this question.